# How to check permissions on currently-viewed model in Django admin template

Tags: python, django, templates

How do you check whether the logged in user has add/change/etc permissions for the currently-viewed model? I'm trying to override `object-tools-items` in `admin/change_list_object_tools.html` with custom buttons, but I can't seem to figure out how to check if the user can make changes for that model to decide whether the button appears or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can user [perm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions) variable inside the template to check for specific permissions:

```
{% if perms.your_app_label.permission_name %}
    do something here
{% endif %}
```

Make sure you have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is [enabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) in settings.

Comment: Won't I need to change `your_app_label` per app? I was wondering if I could just override the file once and have it check against the currently-viewed model, whatever it is, and whichever app it's from.

Comment: @Zoetrophy, I do believe it's possible - according to a code-base Django uses this in `change_list.html` template: `{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-list{% endblock %}`. So, you can create a custom [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), pass the context into it and use it in `if` condition - then you'll not need to hardcode app labels or permission names.